# How to integrate qunit with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, integration, qunit

How can I integrate **`qunit`** with eclipse? I could not find a plugin for the same in Eclipse marketplace.

- Is there any other way by which I can integrate the two?
- Should it be through JS Test Driver?

Comment: This question is not about programming. You may want to move it to: [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this:

- Download and install the headless browser "[phantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)". It has a plugin for launching qunit tasks.
- In Eclipse, define a menu item Run/External Tools/Configuration with a command line like this

  phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs phantomjs/run-qunit.js nttp://mysite.com/myproject/tests/qunit-composite.html

If you have many test scripts and test cases, and if want to store your run results in a database, then additionally do this:

- Install the Build Server TeamCity, it is free and has an Eclipse plugin.
- Configure and start TeamCity from the command line.
- In TeamCity, add a new project with a single Build Step with the phantomjs call mentioned above

All this brings more complexity of course.